# Dynamically create radio buttons in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, radio-button, shinydashboard

I am currently modifying a **shiny dashboard** in R and need to create radio buttons dynamically based on the content of a vector that is created in my **server class**:

```
available_years <- c("2019", "2020", "2021") 
output$available_years <- reactive(available_years) 
outputOptions(output, "available_years", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
```

In the **UI class** I want to use this to create the radio buttons like this:

```
fluidRow(
                  #Input Buttons for years 
                  column(3, 
                         radioButtons("radioYear", h4(paste("Available years:")), 
                                      choices = list("2019" = "2019", 
                                                     "2020" = "2020", 
                                                     "2021" = "2021")))
                ),
```

But instead of hard-coding it, I would like to take the length of the vector instead of the *3* and the content of the vector instead of of the hard-coded *list*.
In terms of **pseudo-code** it would look like this:

```
 fluidRow(
              #Input Buttons for years 
              column(length(output.available_years), 
                     radioButtons("radioYear", h4(paste("Available years:")), 
                                  choices = list(for(i in length(output.available_years){
                                    output.available_years[i] = output.available_years[i]
                                  }))))
            ),
```

I am thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide the dataset in server function along with `render` commands and call them using `uiOutput` in ui function. This will enable you to get the values dynamic based on the vector.

Code with sample data:

```
Data <- c('2019', '2020', '2021', '2022')

ui <- fluidRow(
  #Getting values from server function
  uiOutput('radioYear')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
 output$radioYear <- renderUI({
   Data <- Data
   column(length(Data), 
      radioButtons("radioYear", h4(paste("Available years:")), 
                   choices = Data))
 })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```